# Product is available to buy in increments of x

Tags: magento2, addtocart, shopping-cart-price-rules

In Magento 1.x, a pop up used to appear when the shopping cart did not contain the correct quantity increment according to the inventory setting in the backend.

In M2, I do not see that message.
Instead, there is only a hardly noticable red-frame around the Qty block.

Is there a back-end setting that should generate the quantity increment error message in case the shopping cart quantity does not match the backend increment setting?

[image: quantity increment in Magento 1.x]
[image: quantity increment in Magento 2.x]

Answer (score 0):

Solution is here:

[No error message shown when purchase qty mismatch the 'Qty Increments' setup](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/b3b89a3f02101490e4fbbb99f23729d623a8baa7)

Answer (score -1):

Please go through this link can help
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-set-a-minimum-quantity-allowed-in-cart-in-Magento-2

Comment: That is not a default Magento Theme, I guess??

Comment: is that your own custom theme?